# Sony Movie Studio Platinum 13 - Rendering output movie freezes, or has glitches in rendered file

Tags: video-editor, render

Using Sony Movie Studio Platinum 13 on Windows 10, the output movie freezes at random points or has glitches/artifacts within the rendered movie file. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get a reliable output movie?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following to work:

1. Restart the PC
2. Reset Movie Studio settings to default by:

   - Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> when starting program
   - When the software starts to load, a window asks, *Do you want to reset all program preferences to default?* Select **Yes**.
   - Make sure to tick the checkbox, *Delete all cached application data*.
3. Deleting all .sfk files can also help with problem projects
4. The default MP4 and AVCHD files seem to be pretty reasonable quality, and less error-prone.

Extracted tips from: https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/208/883399